# Google Maps API: Calculate Center/Zoom of Polyline

Tags: google-maps, overlay, polyline

I have an overlay that is dynamically generated from user data, so I need to know how to find the center of that overlay.

Currently, I am just using the first coordinates from the overlay, but that really does not represent the center of the overlay.  Therefore when I load the map, it is not centered on the overlay.

Does anyone have a good method for centering the map on the overlay, by calculating the center, not hard coding it?

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.269239, -122.276010);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,//Calculate this somehow?
        center: latlng,// Calculate value from array of coordinates?
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you have a list of coordinates, you can loop over them and add them to a [LatLngBounds](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds) object. Here is a example for the V3 API, but the concept in V2 is similar:

```js
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
  bounds.extend(coordinates[i]);
}
```

After that, you can get the center with:

```js
bounds.getCenter();
```

Or alternatively, you can call `map.fitBounds()` directly, which will center the map around the center of the bounds  and adjust the zoom, so that the whole bounds will fit exactly into the view port.

```js
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Could this same method be used to calculate the zoom?

Comment: Just use any position and zoom level you want during the initialization and call `map.fitBounds(bounds);` afterwards as described. If you want to enforce some maximum zoom level, you will need to register a `zoomChangeBoundsListener` temporarily. Tell me if you need an example for that too.

Comment: that worked alright in V2 of the api. in V3 the LatLngBounds must receive these 2 variables in this order: SW and NE, how do we know which is which?

Answer (score 15):

Based on @tux21b,

```
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      polyline.getPath().forEach(function(e){//can't do polyline.getPath()[i] because it's a MVCArray
          bounds.extend(e);
      })         
      _map.fitBounds(bounds);
```